# How to combine an external preloader with actual SWF file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an external preloader that loads my swf file. How can I combine these two to upload them on the internet? I cannot add the preloader in the first frame of my original swf and move the layers to the second layer as this tampers with my file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the preloader as a different file so do not try to combine them. Just upload both of the files to the webserver and to your html file include only the preloader.swf. Make sure that your preloader is calling the correct file in its Loader.load() method.

Comment: Would it be better if I made the preloader the .swf file and the original .swf file the html one?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand. You should have 2 files, one preloader, that only has the code for preloading, nothing more (maybe some graphical interface with a bar, etc..) and your main file, which you want to load with this preloader. You include the preloader.swf in your html markup, do NOT include the other main.swf in the html. Check this video if you do not know how to create a preloader: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=85